# Degrees of freedom in quadratic regression simultaneous confidence bands

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, degrees-of-freedom

I have been working on an inverse regression addon for SPSS and using this paper heavily:
[I. Lavagnini, F. Magno, A statistical overview on univariate calibration, inverse regression, and detection limits: Application to gas chromatography/mass spectrometry technique., Mass spectrometry reviews 26, 1-18 (2007).](http://ge.tt/9l1m1iI/v/0)

They do a good job of explaining the difference between the simultaneous and non-simultaneous bands for linear regression, i.e. using $t_{1-{\frac\alpha  2},n-2}$ for non-simultaneous vs $\sqrt{2F^\alpha _{2,n-2}}$ for simultaneous as follows:
$$
y^{\pm} = b_0+b_1x\pm t_{1-{\frac\alpha  2},n-2}s_R\sqrt{{\frac 1 N}+{\frac {(x-\bar x)^2} {\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}}}
$$

and

$$
y^{\pm} = b_0+b_1x\pm \sqrt{2F^\alpha _{2,n-2}}s_R\sqrt{{\frac 1 N}+{\frac {(x-\bar x)^2} {\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}}}
$$

...But they do not give the analogous simultaneous multiplier for quadratic regression. Do the two degrees of freedom in the $\sqrt{2F^\alpha _{2,n-2}}$ term come from having 2 regression coefficients in linear regression or from having two variables, the independent and dependent?

**My question stated briefly:**

Should my simultaneous multiplier in quadratic regression be $\sqrt{2F^\alpha _{2,n-3}}$ or $\sqrt{2F^\alpha _{3,n-3}}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Neither.  (But they are good guesses.)

This is called [Scheffe's Method](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Alex_Shapiro/spl05.pdf).  The multiplier (see formula 1.2 in the link) is $\sqrt{p F^\alpha_{p, n-p}}$ for $p$ parameters and $n$ independent observations.  For linear regression there are $p=2$ parameters (intercept and slope); for quadratic regression there are $p=3$ parameters (intercept, slope, and quadratic term): see Section E in the reference ("Quadratic Calibration Curve").

However, I'm not so sure you can derive the same formula for quadratic regression: those bands are really the tops of tubes in three dimensions and surely they must also include terms involving the *squares* of the $x_i$ (and consequently their fourth powers) in addition to the $x_i$ themselves.

Comment: Right to the point. Thanks for the help! Updating my code now.

Comment: I don't recommend accepting this reply, because it is incomplete. I am hoping it might remind some better-informed readers of the theory and perhaps they can contribute better answers.

Comment: oh ok, I will do some further reading as well. I un-checked your answer even though it was really helpful.